# How to handle JWT.exp time?

Tags: javascript, date, jwt, momentjs

```
console.log('DEBUG::+jwtDecode(token).exp', +jwtDecode(token).exp); //1534820211

console.log('DEBUG::try', new Date(+jwtDecode(token).exp).toISOString());
//DEBUG::try 1970-01-18T18:20:20.211Z
```

I'm having a token with value `1534820211` and when I try to convert it using `toISOString()` it gives me year `1970-01-18T18:20:20.211Z`.

But when I decode the same token at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), and mouse hover over `exp`, it shows `2018-08-21....` which is huge difference. I have also tried to pass `jwtDecode(token).exp` into `moment` and using format, still return me datetime in `1970xxxx`.

```
moment(jwtDecode(token).exp).format();
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The value you have is *seconds from epoch*.

JavaScript `Date` constructor (and `moment` function too) accepts value in *milliseconds from epoch*. Multiply the number by 1000, and your code should work fine:

```js
var exp = 1534820211 * 1000;
console.log(new Date(exp));
```